# Python requests put request to shopify api always gives error

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am calling shopify api to image upload in shopify theme through python requests library. I am using put request but it always gives me error like :{'error': "822: unexpected token at 'asset=key&asset=attachment'"} for any put request.

Here is my headers:-

```
 endpoint_api_image =  "https://{0}/admin/themes/{1}/assets.json".format(shop,theme_id)
headers = {
    # 'Accept': 'application/json',
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
}
```

Here is my request to api:-

```
data={
"asset": {
    "key": image_name,
    "attachment": encoded_image
    }
}
image_url =requests.put(endpoint_api_image,headers=headers, data=data)
print(image_url.json())
```

The response i am getting:

```
{'error': "822: unexpected token at 'asset=key&asset=attachment'"}.
```

Where i am missing the point? It is happening for any put requests.Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is expecting JSON, but you are posting form-encoded data. Use the `json` parameter to the requests.put.

```
image_url =requests.put(endpoint_api_image, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Note, there's a [Python client](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api) for Shopify that might be easier to use.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Such a silly mistake. You made my day!